# Как сделать INSERT в таблицу для записей условие для которых выполнится успешно?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, foreign-key

Есть 2 связанных между собой таблицы. 1-я таблица `TABLE1` имеет колонки `id` и `name`. Вторая таблица `TABLE2` имеет колонку `id_table1`(`id` из первой таблицы) и другие колонки. 
Как можно вставить в `TABLE2` записи, для которых условие `TABLE1.id` = `TABLE2.id_table1` будет успешным? Я пробовал конструкцию `INSERT INTO tablename(column1, colum2...) VALUES(1, 2) WHERE...УСЛОВИЕ`, но потом почитав понял, что такая конструкция не поддерживается.

У меня получилось выбрать значения `id` тех колонок, в которые мне нужно вставить новые значения таким запросом. Вопрос лишь в том, как прикрутить эту выборку к условию, по которому будет произведён `INSERT`.

```
SELECT table2.id_table1
  FROM table2, table1
 WHERE table2.id_table1 = table1.id 
   AND table1.code = 'SOME_CODE';
```

Извините, если пишу бред, старался объяснить максимально доступно.

Comment: Как называется Ваша СУБД ? лучше добавьте сразу тегом

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: используйте конструкцию вида `insert into table(a,b,c) select x, y, z ...` где в качестве select пишите свой запрос, который собственно возвращает нужные id только в случае, когда эти записи надо вставить. так же обращаю ваше внимание, что запрос не обязан получать все данные из таблицы, он вполне может возращать константы, например `select id, 'константа1', 2 from ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (id_table1, Col2, Col3, ..)
SELECT table2.id_table1, Col1, Col2, ...
FROM   table2, table1
WHERE  table2.id_table1 = table1.id 
AND    table1.code = 'SOME_CODE';
```